# Starting Shiny app after password input (with Shinydashboard)

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

In this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input?rq=1) is well explained how to start the shinyapp after some password input. I am trying to do the same, but instead of "navbarPage", I would like to have a "dashboardPage".

I tried to change the argument in do.call function form 'navbarPage' to 'dashboardPage', but the app crashes.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

Logged = FALSE;
my_username <- "test"
my_password <- "test"

ui1 <- function(){
  tagList(
    div(id = "login",
        wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
                  passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                  br(),actionButton("Login", "Log in"))),
    tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -150px;}")
  )}

ui2 <- function(){tagList(tabPanel("Test"))}

ui = (htmlOutput("page"))
server = (function(input, output,session) {

  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)

  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
          Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
          if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
            if (Id.username == Id.password) {
              USER$Logged <- TRUE
            } 
          }
        } 
      }
    }    
  })
  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {

      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))
      })
    }
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) 
    {
      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(dashboardPage,c(inverse=TRUE,title = "Contratulations you got in!",ui2())))
      })
      print(ui)
    }
  })
})

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Since you linked to the post you don't have to copy their code. Please rather post YOUR code and what doesn't work.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: for future reader stop any think and check [this](https://gist.github.com/harveyl888/3e5123a6469fbdc3830123e3efb31a2a)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I woder if my code is enough to get you started on the "right" path. Please let me know if it is not the case.

The code below, if the login and password are correct, will display a shinydashboard.

but the following issues will need addressing:

- There is a problem in the css.  I think you need to "reset" the css changed for the login operation to something more standard to shinydashboard (currently it is all white)
- If the password is wrong, the first `observe` will keep on "winning" on the renderUI (with or without a second `observe`, strictly speaking unnecessary hence eliminated) and the message relative to the wrong login is never executed.

There are number of things you could try to fix the above.

- For the css you could either re-set it, or elegantly have the login in a modal.
- For the second perhaps you could bring all the logic into the renderUI call. This would make sure that all cases are executed.

But please let me know if it is clear enough.

This is the code:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

Logged = FALSE

my_username <- "test"
my_password <- "test"

ui1 <- function() {
  tagList(
    div(
      id = "login",
      wellPanel(
        textInput("userName", "Username"),
        passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
        br(),
        actionButton("Login", "Log in")
      )
    ),
    tags$style(
      type = "text/css",
      "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -150px;}"
    )
  )
}

ui2 <- function() {
  tagList(dashboardHeader(),
          dashboardSidebar(),
          dashboardBody("Test"))
}


ui = (htmlOutput("page"))

server = function(input, output, session) {
  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)

  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (length(input$Login) > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
          Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
          if (length(Id.username) > 0 &
              length(Id.password) > 0) {
            if (Id.username == Id.password) {
              USER$Logged <- TRUE
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })

  output$page <- renderUI({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      do.call(bootstrapPage, c("", ui1()))
    } else {
      do.call(dashboardPage, #c(inverse=TRUE,title = "Contratulations you got in!",
              ui2())
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**October 30, 2017 Update**

It seems that the above code doesn't work anymore (thanks to @5249203 for pointing this out).

I've tried to fix it, but I haven't managed to make the `do.call` function work with `dashboardBody`  (if somebody knows of a way, please let me know!).

Therefore I approached the problem in another way, thanks to recent `shiny` functions.

See what you think (of course as usual the solution is just a template needing extensions).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

Logged = FALSE
my_username <- "test"
my_password <- "test"

ui <- dashboardPage(skin='blue',
  dashboardHeader( title = "Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody("Test",
    # actionButton("show", "Login"),
  verbatimTextOutput("dataInfo")
    )
)

server = function(input, output,session) {

values <- reactiveValues(authenticated = FALSE)

# Return the UI for a modal dialog with data selection input. If 'failed' 
# is TRUE, then display a message that the previous value was invalid.
dataModal <- function(failed = FALSE) {
  modalDialog(
    textInput("username", "Username:"),
    passwordInput("password", "Password:"),
    footer = tagList(
      # modalButton("Cancel"),
      actionButton("ok", "OK")
    )
  )
}

# Show modal when button is clicked.  
# This `observe` is suspended only whith right user credential

obs1 <- observe({
  showModal(dataModal())
})

# When OK button is pressed, attempt to authenticate. If successful,
# remove the modal. 

obs2 <- observe({
  req(input$ok)
  isolate({
    Username <- input$username
    Password <- input$password
  })
  Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
  Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
  if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
    if (Id.username == Id.password) {
      Logged <<- TRUE
        values$authenticated <- TRUE
        obs1$suspend()
        removeModal()

    } else {
      values$authenticated <- FALSE
    }     
  }
  })


output$dataInfo <- renderPrint({
  if (values$authenticated) "OK!!!!!"
  else "You are NOT authenticated"
})

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thx, it worked!! For some reason the shinydashboard´s color palette was desconfigured, but nothing we can adjust via css.

Comment: @Enzo, I tried your code, but it just refreshes login page for me. am I missing something?

Comment: @user5249203 Posting some changes

Comment: @user5249203 Please let me know if the new version works for you.

Comment: @Enzo, thank you it works. Why did you use `Logged <<- TRUE`, double `<<` symbol here?

Comment: I thought to provide another way to check if the user has been logged successfully.  `Logged` is available to be tested. I'm sure you are familiar with this R operator: "The operators <<- and ->> are normally only used in functions, and cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned". It is the way to assign value to a variable defined "outside" of the `shiny` functions. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947142/when-to-use-a-reactive-expression-vs-to-use-to-create-a-global-object/45949043#45949043.  Enzo

Comment: I would urge caution with this approach -- make sure to check explicitly for Logged == TRUE in each component of your app: it's fairly easy to use Inspector mode in any modern browser to simply delete the authentication modal -- if you only check for the authentication status in the modal itself, someone could just delete the modal and then use the app behind it

Comment: Currently, you have to use your mouse to click the "OK" button. Is there a way to use the "Enter" key on the keyboard to make it work? I have seen an example here but cannot make it work for this situation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335951/using-enter-key-with-action-button-in-r-shiny I am also trying to keep all code within the app versus using multiple files.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution that takes a slightly different approach than @Enzo's. It creates a second UI so users cannot see what the app is displaying on the first menu tab. The only downside is everything is basically brought to the Server side which may cause some issues for your code depending on how it is written.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

my_username <- "test"
my_password <- "abc"

###########################/ui.R/##################################

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "my heading")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebarpanel"))
body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("body") )

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

###########################/server.R/##################################

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  Logged <- FALSE

  USER <<- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)

  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
          Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
          if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
            if (Id.username == Id.password) {
              USER$Logged <<- TRUE
            } 
          }
        } 
      }
    }    
  })

  output$sidebarpanel <- renderUI({
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) { 
      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarUserPanel("myuser", subtitle = a(icon("user"), "Logout", href="")),
        selectInput("in_var", "myvar", multiple = FALSE,
                    choices = c("option 1","option 2")),
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Item 1", tabName = "t_item1", icon = icon("line-chart")),
          menuItem("Item 2", tabName = "t_item2", icon = icon("dollar")),
          menuItem("Item 3", tabName = "t_item3", icon = icon("credit-card")),
          menuItem("Item 4", tabName = "t_item4", icon = icon("share-alt"))
        ))}
  })

  output$body <- renderUI({
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {
      B <- c(2,3,4,3,7,5,4)

      box(
        title = p("Histogram", actionLink("Expand", "", icon = icon("expand"))), status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, width = 4,
        hist(B)
      )
    }
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      box(title = "Login",textInput("userName", "Username"),
          passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
          br(),
          actionButton("Login", "Log in"))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**September 2018 Update**

I was able to figure out @Enzo's original code to make the `do.call` function work with `shinydashboard`. Please see below. Credit to @Enzo for this, I just slightly changed some lines. I think this solution is better than my first code above since it allows the correct output codes to stay in the UI side. I've also added a message pop-up if the username and password is incorrect.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

my_username <- "test"
my_password <- "abc"

###########################/ui.R/##################################

ui1 <- function(){
  tagList(
    div(id = "login",
        wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
                  passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                  br(),
                  actionButton("Login", "Log in"),
                  verbatimTextOutput("dataInfo")
        )
    ),
    tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -150px;}")
  )}

ui2 <- function(){tagList(
  "You did it!"
)}

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Test Login")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$head(tags$style("#dataInfo{color: red")),
  htmlOutput("page")
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

###########################/server.R/##################################

server = (function(input, output,session) {

  Logged <- FALSE
  Security <- TRUE

  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)
  SEC <- reactiveValues(Security = Security)

  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          if(my_username == Username & my_password == Password) {
            USER$Logged <- TRUE
          } else {SEC$Security <- FALSE}
        } 
      }
    }    
  })

  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {output$page <- renderUI({ui1()})}
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {output$page <- renderUI({ui2()})}
  })

  observe({
    output$dataInfo <- renderText({
      if (SEC$Security) {""}
      else {"Your username or password is not correct"}
    })
  })

})

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Once I logout it is showing 404 Not Found. How to solve this ? It should show the login page again.

Comment: I solved it by replacing     
sidebarUserPanel("myuser",subtitle = a(icon("user"), "Logout", href="__logout__"))      with      sidebarUserPanel("myuser",subtitle = a(icon("user"), "Logout", href=""))

Comment: Nice comment, didn't even notice that it didn't work! I will update above.

Comment: Is there a way to have ui2 load directly into the first tab if I replace the tagList() call with a tabItems() call?  I get a blank ui after successfully logging in.  I can click the sidebar to get to the first tab, but I'd like to have the first tab automatically displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your example uses a single user. I made some modifications for multiple user/password situations. This seems to work for me. Hopefully, others may find it helpful:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

user_base <- tibble(
  user =     c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3"),
  password = c("abc", "bcd", "cde"),
  name =     c("User1", "User2", "User3")
)

###########################/ui.R/##################################

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "my heading")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebarpanel"))
body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("body") )
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

###########################/server.R/##################################

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  Logged <- FALSE

  USER <<- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)

  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          Id.username <- which(user_base$user == Username)
          Id.password <- which(user_base$password == Password)
          if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
            if (Id.username == Id.password) {
              USER$Logged <<- TRUE
            } 
          }
        } 
      }
    }    
  })

  output$sidebarpanel <- renderUI({
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) { 
      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarUserPanel("myuser", subtitle = a(icon("user"), "Logout", href="")),
        selectInput("in_var", "myvar", multiple = FALSE,
                    choices = c("option 1","option 2")),
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Item 1", tabName = "t_item1", icon = icon("line-chart")),
          menuItem("Item 2", tabName = "t_item2", icon = icon("dollar")),
          menuItem("Item 3", tabName = "t_item3", icon = icon("credit-card")),
          menuItem("Item 4", tabName = "t_item4", icon = icon("share-alt"))
        ))}
  })

  output$body <- renderUI({
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {
      B <- c(2,3,4,3,7,5,4)

      box(
        title = p("Histogram", actionLink("Expand", "", icon = icon("expand"))), 
        status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, width = 4,
        hist(B)
      )
    }
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      box(title = "Login",textInput("userName", "Username"),
          passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
          br(),
          actionButton("Login", "Log in"))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```