# Adding static login page to R shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have this initial shiny dashboard that I assembeled together:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(readxl)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(dropdownMenuOutput("messageMenu"), 
                  dropdownMenuOutput("notificationMenu")),
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("ImportForcast", tabName = "ImportForcast", icon = icon("arrow-down")),
      menuItem("Visualization", tabName = "Visualization", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Help", tabName = "Help", icon = icon("list-alt") ),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
       
    )
  ),
  
  ## Body content
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              )
      ),
      
      tabItem(tabName = "ImportForcast",
              fluidRow(
                
                
                
                span(headerPanel("Import  forcast  file"), style="color:red"), 
                
                sidebarPanel(
                  
                  radioButtons("pdt", "Choisir produit:",
                               c("Option1" = "Option1",
                                 "Option2" = "Option2")),
                  
                  fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                            accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')),
                  
                  tags$hr()
                  
                ), 
                actionButton("do", "Export/View"),
                
                dataTableOutput('table'),
                
                mainPanel(
                  # dygraphOutput("hdpePlot"),
                  textOutput("text"),
                  tableOutput('contents')
                )
                
                
                
              )
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "Visualization",
              titlePanel("Forcast Dataset"),
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                  radioButtons("x", "Select X-axis:",
                               list("date"='a')),
                  radioButtons("y", "Select Y-axis:",
                               list('X000'='f', "inflation"='b',"X004"='c',"X008"='d', "X009"='e','X014'='j'))
                
                ),
                mainPanel(
                  textOutput("msg"),
                  plotOutput("distPlot")
                )
              )
      ),
      
      tabItem(tabName = "Help",
              fluidRow(
                h2("    Help :  "),
                h1("    Installation guide :  "), 
                h3("    Contact :  "), 
                
                box(title = "Histogram", status = "primary", plotOutput("plot2", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Inputs", status = "warning",
                  "Box content here", br(), "More box content",
                  sliderInput("slider", "Slider input:", 1, 100, 50),
                  textInput("text", "Text input:")
                ),
                
                
                box(
                  title = "Histogram", background = "maroon", solidHeader = TRUE,
                  plotOutput("plot4", height = 250)
                ),
                
                box(
                  title = "Inputs", background = "black",
                  "Box content here", br(), "More box content",
                  sliderInput("slider", "Slider input:", 1, 100, 50),
                  textInput("text", "Text input:")
                )
                
                
              )
      ),
      
      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content")
      )
    )
  )
  
)


#Server 
server <- function(input, output) {
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
 
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
    
  })
  
  #Show success message if data is successfuly imported
  output$text<- reactive({
    validate(
      need(is.null(input$file1) , "Import Success")
    
    )
    "Not imported file yet"
  })
  
  #Show msg that inform the user that he must import file before visualization
  output$msg<- reactive({
    validate(
      need(!is.null(input$file1) , "You must import file for visualization")
      
    )
    "Enjoy visualisation"
  })
  output$dataForcast<- reactive({
    
    dataForcast<- read_excel(input$file1)
    })
  dataForcast <- read_excel("./Forcast.xlsx",
                            sheet = 1, na = "NA",
                            skip = 1)
  output$table <- renderDataTable(dataForcast)
  # Saving files
  saveRDS(dataForcast,file="./forcast/RDS/dataForcast.Rds")
  write.csv(dataForcast, file = "./forcast/RDS/dataForcastt.csv", row.names = FALSE) 
  

  df <- eventReactive(input$do, {
    dataForcast <- read_excel("./Forcast.xlsx", 
                              sheet = 1, na = "NA", 
                              skip = 1)
    output$table <- renderDataTable(dataForcast)
  })
  
  # output$do<- reactive({
  #   
  #   output$table <- renderDataTable(dataForcast)
  # })
  
  
  #The visualisation of the data
  output$distPlot<- renderPlot({ 
  if(!is.null(input$file1) )
   { 
   
   
    if(input$x=='a'){
      i<-1}
    if(input$y=='b'){
      j<-54}
    if(input$y=='c'){
      j<-4}
    if(input$y=='d'){
      j<-9}
    if(input$y=='e'){
      j<-10 }
    if(input$y=='f'){
      j<-2 }
    if(input$y=='j'){
      j<-14 }
   
     s    <- dataForcast[, i]
     k    <- dataForcast[, j]
    x2 <- data.frame(s,k)
    plot(x2)
 } 
  })

  #Notification is generated on the server   
    output$notificationMenu <- renderMenu({
      #Initalisation of notification
      col_headings <- c('message','status')
      # notificationData <- data.frame(' 12 items delivered', 'success')
      notificationData<- read.csv('msgs.csv')
      names(notificationData) <- col_headings
      #add a notification of success importation
      if(!is.null(input$file1))
        {
        not_sucess<- data.frame('Import Success', 'success')
        names(not_sucess) <- col_headings
        notificationData<-rbind(not_sucess, notificationData)
        }
      
      nots <- apply(notificationData, 1, function(row) {
        notificationItem(text = row[["message"]], status = row[["status"]])
      })
      dropdownMenu(type = "notifications", .list = nots)
    })
    

  #Message is generated on the server 
  output$messageMenu<- renderMenu({
    dropdownMenu(type = "messages",
                 messageItem(
                   from = "Sales Dept",
                   message = "Sales are steady this month."
                 ),
                 messageItem(
                   from = "New User",
                   message = "How do I register?",
                   icon = icon("question"),
                   time = "13:45"
                 ),
                 messageItem(
                   from = "Support",
                   message = "The new server is ready.",
                   icon = icon("life-ring"),
                   time = "2014-12-01"
                 )
    )
  })
  

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried to add a login page but it was not succesfull :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
source("admin.R")

my_username <- c("test","admin")
my_password <- c("test","123")
get_role=function(user){
  
  if(user=="test") {
    
    return("TEST")
  }else{
    
    return("ADMIN")
  }
}

get_ui=function(role){
  itog=list()
  if(role=="TEST"){
    itog$title=test_title
    itog$main=test_main
    itog$side=test_side
    return(itog)
  }else{
    itog$title=admin_title
    itog$main=admin_main
    itog$side=admin_side
    return(itog)
  }
}


shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  
  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = FALSE,role=NULL)
  
  ui1 <- function(){
    tagList(
      div(id = "login",
          wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
                    passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                    br(),actionButton("Login", "Log in")))
      ,tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -10px;margin-left: -150px;}")
    )}
  
  
  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
          Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
          if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
            if (Id.username == Id.password) {
              USER$Logged <- TRUE
              USER$role=get_role(Username)
              
            }
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  })
  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      
      output$page <- renderUI({
        box(
          div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1()))))
      })
    }
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE)    {
      output$page <- ui # ui from the first dashboard
    }
  })
})
```

With the second code I get the login box as in the following screen capture:

[image]

After I change this block :

```
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE)    {
      output$page <- ui # ui from the first dashboard
    }
```

I get the new interface on displayed but the old side menu is still there, so it's dashboard inside of another dashboard, because I just integrated the whole interface in just output$page.

Is there an easier solution to add login page to the first dashboard ?
Or a way to integrate the login (second code) with the first dashboard (first code) so the user can login and the dashboard is displayed?

Comment: I've just amended my earlier answer to a similar question, as the code doesn't seem to work anymore. I've used a different method for login.  See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404058/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input-with-shinydashboard/43413216?noredirect=1#comment79818287_43413216