# When to use a reactive expression vs to use <<- to create a global object

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to create a Shiny app using some functions that my coworker created. He often uses the '<<-' operator in his functions to create global objects.

Questions:
1. Is it a good practice to use <<- in this case?
2. Will the app be faster if I use reactive() to represent the objects?
3. Any better suggestions?

Here is an example of the function he wrote:

```
PrepareData<-function(pickoneperday=TRUE,data) { 
  set.seed(1)
  if (pickoneperday==TRUE) {data <<- PickOnePerDay(data)} 
  data <<- RankData(data)
  SetMeasureType()
  minnodebase <<- 0.005*nrow(data)
  CodeMissingData(data)
}
```

Comment: Why does your co-worker do this? It makes re-using functions very difficult. And you're really only concerned with "faster" here? And not "correct"? A more complete [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: `reactive()` and `<<-` do two very different things. `reactive()` allows a thing (data frame for example) to react to user input. `<<-` as you say assigns global objects. They are not really interchangeable. Also, I don't really understand why your coworker does that.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The app runs noticably slow so I wonder if him using << explains the slowness. It looks like a better practice would be to rewrite the function (by avoiding <<) instead of using reactive(). Any other suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Agree with other commenters - you should not adopt your coworker's practice. If you need to return objects from a function the correct way to do it is to use `return(data)`. Otherwise you're just asking for monstrously confusing bugs down the road.

Comment: "Is it a good practice to use `<<-`...": **NO**.  You can also have multiple reactive values update after an event by having them depend on one another, so each can be directly assigned in the server loop.

Comment: ShinyChat is an interesting example. It uses both global and session reactiveValues not because those are 'good style', but because those are what the app requires. A chat app needs to share live data (chat text, users) between different users in different sessions. `<<-` is used to update the value of a global object in the global (shared) environment. When first created, vars is defined using `<-`, and global objects can be updated in the session/local environment using `<-`. Use global variables only if your app requires them. Use `<<-` or `<-` depending on the scope/environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the outset, I think we need to clarify the scope of the question.

1. If you write a function in R, it is good practice to return value using either `return()` at the end of the function, for clarity, or at least putting the data object last before the curly brackets. in this context, the use of `<<-` can create any sort of errors and complications (in short is a reminder of spaghetti programming, breaking the rule of having a single exit point to the function in question).
2. Different is the case of `shiny` special functions. I just like to remind that `shiny` coders usually does not use `return()` at the end of a shiny function (even if it would still work). Here either there is no value returned, or `reactive` is used or other similar constructs.

Part of the confusion comes from the minimal example in the question: the example is not a `shiny` special function but just a normal function.

In `shiny`, using for example constructs like `observe`, it may happen to use `<<-` to update global objects.  A very good example (a great piece of code I often go back to) is the application ShinyChat developed by Jeff Allen, one of shiny developers - [see here on github](https://github.com/trestletech/ShinyChat).
In this case Jeff uses  `<<-` to update a reactiveValue defined at the global level from within an `observe` function: very good style.

I conclude with a minor point: if you have any function and you update a variable with  `<<-`, and you have a variable of the same name defined locally, only the global variable is updated.
In these cases you need to do something like

```
data <<- data <- 3
```

From right to left: the first `<-` updated the local variable named `data`: the second `<<-` updated the global variable named `data`.  Talk about confusing.

On the other hand, in shiny or standard R I never noticed a drastic slowness because of `<<-`, certainly provided that there aren't too many in the code.

On the issue of alternative techniques like `reactive` or `reactiveValues`, please see this good answer on SO to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436713/r-shiny-reactivevalues-vs-reactive).

Comment: Point taken. I rewrote all `<<` as `<<-`. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough explanation.