# R Shiny: How to hide tabPanel by a condition in server

Tags: r, shiny, tabpanel

I modified an answer given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404058/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input-with-shinydashboard) to write a very simple login/logout system using the [Shiny](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shiny/shiny.pdf) package in R. I would like to hide panel "B" if USER$Logged is FALSE (i.e. user is logged out) and show it whenever USER$Logged is TRUE (i.e. user is logged in). In other words, once you run the code, it should not show panel B, until the user correctly enter username and password. I tried to use conditionalPanel but it does not hide panel B. It is currently showing it all the time regardless of USER$Logged. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
my_username <- "test"
my_password <- "abc"
shinyApp(
  shinyUI(
    navbarPage( tabPanel("A", uiOutput('loginpage')),
               tabPanel("B", uiOutput('page1'),conditionalPanel(condition = "output.cond1==TRUE"))
                            )
                            ),
  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    USER <<- reactiveValues(Logged = FALSE)
    observe({
      if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
        output$loginpage <- renderUI({
          box(title = "",textInput("userName", "Username"),
              passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
              br(),
              actionButton("Login", "Log in"))})
      } else if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {
        output$loginpage <- renderUI({fluidPage(
          box(title = "",br(),br(),actionButton("logout", "Logout"))
        )

        })
      }
    })

    observeEvent(input$Login, {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
          Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
          if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
            if (Id.username == Id.password) {
              USER$Logged <<- TRUE

            } 
          }
        } 
      }

    })

    observeEvent(input$logout, {
      USER$Logged <<- FALSE
    })

    output$cond1 = reactive({
      USER$Logged==TRUE
    })

                       }     ))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `shinyjs` package to show/hide the tab. To do this, I added an `id` to the `navbar` so that we can select the tab to show/hide. The you can add a `shinyjs::show/hide` in your `observe` to show or hide the tab when the user is logged in or out. One last note is you need to call `useShinyjs()` somewhere in your UI so the functions will work. I also made some minor edits to your code (e.g. getting rid of `<<-`. The app is:

```
library(shinyjs)
shinyApp(
  shinyUI(
    navbarPage( id = "navbar",
                useShinyjs(),
                tabPanel("A", uiOutput('loginpage')),
                tabPanel("B", uiOutput('page1'),conditionalPanel(condition = "output.cond1==TRUE"))
    )
  ),
  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = FALSE)

    observe({
      if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
        output$loginpage <- renderUI({
          box(title = "",textInput("userName", "Username"),
              passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
              br(),
              actionButton("Login", "Log in"))})

        shinyjs::hide(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=B]")

      } else if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {
        output$loginpage <- renderUI({fluidPage(
          box(title = "",br(),br(),actionButton("logout", "Logout"))
        )})

        shinyjs::show(selector = "#navbar li a[data-value=B]")
        }

    })

    observeEvent(input$Login, {
          Id.username <- which(my_username == input$userName)
          Id.password <- which(my_password == input$passwd)
          if(Id.username & Id.password) USER$Logged <<- TRUE
    })

    observeEvent(input$logout, {
      USER$Logged <- FALSE
    })
    }))
```

Comment: Hi, your answer was really helpfull for me but there is a short time where the B tabpanel is visible before being hidden. Is there a way to skip this ?