# Run code to create table and download table

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I just started to use Shiny and I'm having some troubles with my code. I tried several codes and searched a lot but I can't figure out how to create what I need.

I have a .R file that has several formulas and in the end returns a .csv file. I need to make this more "user friendly", so I'm trying to do that with Shiny.

This is what I've achieved so far...
[image]

So, I need a field to insert a password and if the password is correct, I can press Run Code. The Run Code must run the code with the formulas and create a csv file. Fisrtly I tried to connect the shiny app with .R file, then I tried to insert the code in Shiny and create a table that will be downloaded using the download data button.

**Previous Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

CODE <- function(){
DATA <- data.frame(
   Name = c("Claudia","Dan","Mike","Brian","Gary"),
   Age = c(3,51,20,45,5)
return(DATA)
}


ui<-   fluidPage(tags$head(tags$style(
  HTML('
         #sidebar {
            background-color: #CCCCCC  ;
        }

        body, label, input, button, select { 
          font-family: "Arial";
        }
        <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $("#downloadData").click(function() {
                                var filtered_table_data = $("#DataTables_Table_0").dataTable()._("tr", {"filter":"applied"});
                                Shiny.onInputChange("filtered_table", filtered_table_data);
                            });
                        });
                   </script>')
)),
setBackgroundColor(
  color = c("#FFFFFF", "#999999"),
  gradient = "linear",
  direction = "bottom"
),#headerPanel(
 # HTML('<p><img src="dhp_logo.png"/></p>')
#),
dashboardHeader(title = span("TEST ",style = "color: #999999; font-size: 50px;font-weight: bold")),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(id="sidebar",passwordInput("password", "Password:"),
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  verbatimTextOutput("DHP2021")),
  mainPanel(actionButton("run", "Run Code",icon("refresh", "fa-3x"), width="400px",style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #666666; border-color: #666666")
            ,downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Data'),dataTableOutput("table")
            ))) 
  



server <-   function(input, output, session){
  output$value <- renderText({
    req(input$go)
    isolate(input$password)
  })
  
  Data <- reactive({
    DATA <- input$run
    return(data.frame(DATA))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    Data()
  }, options = list(sDom = "ilftpr"))
  
  ProcessedFilteredData <- reactive({
    v <- input$filtered_table_data
    col_names <- names(Data())
    n_cols <- length(col_names)
    n_row <- length(v)/n_cols
    m <- matrix(v, ncol = n_cols, byrow = TRUE)
    df <- data.frame(m)
    names(df) <- col_names
    return(df)
  })
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 'DATA.csv' }, content = function(file) {
      write.csv(ProcessedFilteredData(), file, row.names = FALSE)
  
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**UPDATE**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

CODE <- function(){
DATA <- data.frame(
   Name = c("Claudia","Dan","Mike","Brian","Gary"),
   Age = c(3,51,20,45,5)
return(DATA)
}

Logged = FALSE

my_username <- "test"
my_password <- "test"


ui1 <- function(){
  tagList(
    div(id = "login",
        wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
                  passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                  br(),
                  actionButton("Login", "Log in"),
                  verbatimTextOutput("dataInfo")
        )
    ),
    tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:30px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;center: 90%}")
  )}


ui2 <- function(){tagList(
  "Successful login!"
)
  mainPanel(actionButton("run", "Run Code",icon("refresh", "fa-3x"), width="400px",style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #666666; border-color: #666666")
                    ,downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Data'),dataTableOutput("table")
                    ) }

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Login")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(htmlOutput("page"))



ui =  dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


server <-   function(input, output, session){
  Logged <- FALSE
  Security <- TRUE
  
  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)
  SEC <- reactiveValues(Security = Security)
  
  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          if(my_username == Username & my_password == Password) {
            USER$Logged <- TRUE
          } else {SEC$Security <- FALSE}
        } 
      }
    }    
  })
  
  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {output$page <- renderUI({ui1()})}
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {output$page <- renderUI({ui2()})}
    if(USER$Logged == TRUE){output$run <- reactiveUI(CODE)}
    if(USER$Logged==TRUE){output$table <- renderDataTable(output$run())}
    if(USER$Logged==TRUE){output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { 'Data.csv' }, content = function(file) {
       write.csv(Data(), file, row.names = FALSE)})
  }})
  
  observe({
    output$dataInfo <- renderText({
      if (SEC$Security) {""}
      else {"Incorrect username or password"}
    })
  })
  
}
```

What is going wrong?

- I can't run code or create the table
- **Warning:** Error in $.shinyoutput: Reading from shinyoutput object is not allowed.

As I previously said, I'm just starting to use Shiny, so probably I'm making code mistakes that I can't perceive yet. I hope the example helps, if you need me to be more enlightening, just say.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice you can give me

=)

Comment: I already managed to solve the password problem. I used the code in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404058/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input-with-shinydashboard . I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: One can only assign a value to the `output` object. Doing `renderDataTable(output$run())` is wrong.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thank you for your comment. I changed that but I still can't create the table.