# Execute Shiny textInput with Return key

Tags: r, text, shiny, user-input

I am creating an R Shiny App that takes text input from the user via `textInput`. Once they are finished, they hit an `actionButton` and the server function processes the text input (for search an the like; this happens thru an `eventReactive` in the server script). This is my code:

```
      SearchTermInput <- function(name_space, 
                                  label = "Search box", button_label = "Search", help_text = NULL) {
      #assign to namespace        
      ns <- NS(name_space)
      #output 
      tagList(
                   # display a litte help tooltip                       
                   tags$div(title = help_text, 
                   #get the text input from user
                   textInput(ns("search_term"), label = label)),
                   # get user input to action button
                   actionButton(ns("execute_search"), label = button_label)
        )
      }
```

- Problem: I would like to give the user the option to alternatively just hit "Enter" to make this run.

I went through the `eventReactive` [docs](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observeEvent.html) and the [help](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/textInput.html) for `textInput` but could not figure out how to do this.

- Question: Is this possible at all? I'm confused on whether I would implement it in `textInput` (reads the user input), as a different `event` similar to the `actionButton`, or how?

I tried searching SO but could not find anything -- any help and pointers are much appreciated!

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent    damn i can't believe I did not find that. Should I delete this one?

Comment: Does it solve your problem ? We can also close. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335951/using-enter-key-with-action-button-in-r-shiny (good question by the way)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent the answers to the other def seemed to do what I was looking for. Idk the policies on here so well so if you don't mind closing it / whatever is necessary, that would be much appreciated! Thanks for pointing me the right way!