# Shiny: Using enter key with action button on login screen

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I created a login screen for my Shiny app and would like users to be able to use the Enter key instead of having to use the mouse to click the OK button. I found an example that looks like it solves it for an input form but unfortunately, it does not work for my example. I am imagining it has something to do with the modal dialog. (have seen a lot of duplicate questions for this topic, this is a new parameter and none of those solutions have solved it)

SO Reference:
[Using enter key with action button in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335951/using-enter-key-with-action-button-in-r-shiny)

Example Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

Logged = FALSE
my_username <- "test"
my_password <- "test"

js <- 

ui <- dashboardPage(skin='blue',
                    dashboardHeader( title = "Dashboard"),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody("Test",
                                  tags$script('
                                      $(document).keyup(function(event) {
                                      if ($("#password").is(":focus") && (event.keyCode == 13)) {
                                      $("#ok").click();
                                      }
                                      });
                                      '),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("dataInfo")
                    )
)

server = function(input, output,session) {

  values <- reactiveValues(authenticated = FALSE)

  # Return the UI for a modal dialog with data selection input. If 'failed' 
  # is TRUE, then display a message that the previous value was invalid.
  dataModal <- function(failed = FALSE) {
    modalDialog(
      textInput("username", "Username:"),
      passwordInput("password", "Password:"),
      footer = tagList(
        # modalButton("Cancel"),
        actionButton("ok", "OK")
      )
    )
  }

  # Show modal when button is clicked.  
  # This `observe` is suspended only whith right user credential

  obs1 <- observe({
    showModal(dataModal())
  })

  # When OK button is pressed, attempt to authenticate. If successful,
  # remove the modal. 

  obs2 <- observe({
    req(input$ok)
    isolate({
      Username <- input$username
      Password <- input$password
    })
    Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
    Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
    if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
      if (Id.username == Id.password) {
        Logged <<- TRUE
        values$authenticated <- TRUE
        obs1$suspend()
        removeModal()

      } else {
        values$authenticated <- FALSE
      }     
    }
  })


  output$dataInfo <- renderPrint({
    if (values$authenticated) "OK!!!!!"
    else "You are NOT authenticated"
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Looking at the source (html) generated by shiny, it looks like the input event is added to the main form (not the modal dialog window) so the enter is not captured by the modal form. Adding the tag$scripts to the modal would give an error (on the browser) and the popup would not run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles upon this thread, this solution (unlike the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32340906/8865518) to the above-linked SO post **Using enter key with action button in R Shiny**) does not require an external js script file.

The `js` script should have been included inside the `modalDialog()` instead, and inside the `HTML()` function, as follows:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

Logged = FALSE
my_username <- "test"
my_password <- "test"

js <- '
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
  if ($("#password").is(":focus") && (event.keyCode == 13)) {
      $("#ok").click();
  }
});
'

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody("Test",
                                  verbatimTextOutput("dataInfo")
                    )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues(authenticated = FALSE)

  # Return the UI for a modal dialog with data selection input. If 'failed' 
  # is TRUE, then display a message that the previous value was invalid.
  dataModal <- function(failed = FALSE) {
    modalDialog(
      tags$script(HTML(js)),
      textInput("username", "Username:"),
      passwordInput("password", "Password:"),
      footer = tagList(
        # modalButton("Cancel"),
        actionButton("ok", "OK")
      )
    )
  }

  # Show modal when button is clicked.  
  # This `observe` is suspended only whith right user credential

  obs1 <- observe({
    showModal(dataModal())
  })

  # When OK button is pressed, attempt to authenticate. If successful,
  # remove the modal. 

  obs2 <- observe({
    req(input$ok)
    isolate({
      Username <- input$username
      Password <- input$password
    })
    Id_username <- which(my_username == Username)
    Id_password <- which(my_password == Password)
    if (length(Id_username) > 0 & length(Id_password) > 0) {
      if (Id_username == Id_password) {
        Logged <<- TRUE
        values$authenticated <- TRUE
        obs1$suspend()
        removeModal()

      } else {
        values$authenticated <- FALSE
      }     
    }
  })


  output$dataInfo <- renderPrint({
    if(values$authenticated){
      "OK!!!!!"
    } else {
      "You are NOT authenticated"
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Also, as a side note, I believe that the js script was originally inspired by [this example](https://gist.github.com/PaulC91/bd5035875305dfad504f1a3794233186).